# Typecasting Character to Int and doing Arithmetic doesn´t work

Tags: c, casting, ascii

**Here is my code and what it does (or should do):**

It iterates through the word/plaintext `string plaintext` that I want to obfuscate. It should iterate `plaintextLength`-many times. The `if`-Statements inside the `for`- Loop make sure that only alphabetical characters are obfuscated. All non-alphabetical characters should just be copied over.

When I input a e.g. `keyword` **baz** and e.g. a `plaintext` **barfoo** then, my code should take the first character of `plaintext`, which would be character **b** (ASCII: 98) and shift it by the first character of `keyword`, which would happen to be also an character **b**. So **b** in `plaintext` should be shifted by number **1**, since **b** in `keyword` is the second character in the alphabet and therefor has an **index** of **1** (i.e. **a/A = 0**, **b/B = 1**, **c/C = 2**, ..., **z/Z = 25**). **b** in `plaintext` will become a **c** (ASCII 99) and this character **c** will be saved in the array `cipher[0]`. The index, by which a character in `plaintext` should be shifted, is calculated by the function `addIndex()`.

However, it all works fine until it gets over ASCII 122. E.g. if we get to the third character **r** (ASCII: 114) in `plaintext`, shifting it by **z** (= 25) would result in ASCII being 139. Therefore when it reaches the end of the alphabet (ASCII 122), it should start again from **a** respectively ASCII 97. This line of code `cipher[i] = 97 + (ascii - 122);` should do this job. But when I run the program, it doesn´t calculate it and saves `ascii` (which is has the value 139) straight in `cipher[2]`.

I think that there is a problem with typecasting but can´t grasp it as to why this happens. I mean `ascii` is an integer value so adding `97` and substracting `122` from 139 shouldn´t be a problem. The result of this calculation would be implicitely casted to an character in order to be saved in the array `cipher[]`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
(...) 

int plaintextLength = strlen(plaintext);
char cipher[plaintextLength];
int ascii;

for (int i = 0; i < plaintextLength; i++)
{
    /* capital letter (ASCII range 65 - 90) */
    if (plaintext[i] >= 'A' &&  plaintext[i] <= 'Z')
    {
        (...)
    }
    /* small letter (ASCII range 97 - 122) */
    else if (plaintext[i] >= 'a' && plaintext[i] <= 'z')
    {
        ascii = plaintext[i] + addIndex(lowerCaseKeyword[i % keywordLength]);

        if (ascii > 'z')
        {
            cipher[i] = 97 + (ascii - 122); // it doesnt calculate it. Why?
        }
        else
        {
            cipher[i] = ascii;
        }
    }
    /* copy over non-aphabetical character */
    else
    {
        (...)
    }
}

(...)

int addIndex(char character)
{
string abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    if (character == abc[i])
    {
        return i;
    }
}

return 0; // ATTETNTION: might return false information but is needed due to compiler bitching around
```

}

Comment: You did not post `addIndex`

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Start a debugger, step through the program and see what is the value of `ascii` before entering the if.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: 113? 112? 123!?

Comment: @alk, ahh! My bad, magic numbers!

Comment: It should be 123 and not 122, moral: don't use magic numbers

Comment: @mnistic edited.

Comment: @малинчекуров Thats what I did before posting this. Turned on debugger and went through my code line for line. Already checked `ascii` gets all the values assigned that I expect. So `ascii` isn´t the source of the problem.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Before my revision of the code, I had instead of the "magic number" the character `'z'` inserted. Thats why I changed `'z'` to `122`. 122 is right. Look into the ASCII table. Wanted to check if that was the problem but no. Program still doesn´t execute as expected.

Comment: @he1zn0erg I know `'z'` is `122`, but you want it to be `123` because the character just after `'z'` should be converted to `'a'` and not `'b'`.

Comment: @he1zn0erg take for instance, ascii is `'{'` (`123`). According to your code, it will become `'b'`. And nothing will map to `'a'` (`'z'` will map to `'a'`, but that will never happen because of the condition). With my adjustment, `'{'` maps to `'a'`.

Comment: To locate your actual problem, try `printf("%d\n", cipher[i]);` after the line you think causes the fault. My guess is the else branch is always being taken. Does the code posted here match exactly what you are running?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Ahh I get it. Thank you very much. It works now!

Comment: just for the vocabulary, in C jargon a cast is an *explicit* conversion. I didn't find any of them in your code.